# Cursor and keyboard input periodically lags/stutters for exactly 3 hours after boot

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, linux-mint

When I boot up my computer the keyboard input and cursor will lag and jitter once every half second for exactly 3 hours. What this means is the cursor will pause for a few miliseconds while being dragged or clicking on something, and then continue, and then studder, and then continue, and so on for exactly 3 hours. The keyboard also isn't able to pick up input during that time as well. After the 3 hours are over everything goes back to normal.

What you're seeing below isn't video lag or computer lag. It's the cursor.

[image]

Notice how the motion isn't smooth like it should be. The cursor pauses while it's being dragged.

This is my system information. I'm using Linux Mint:

```
System:    Host: linux Kernel: 4.15.0-111-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X551MA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X551MA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: X551MA.515 date: 04/15/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: N/A condition: N/A model: N/A status: Unknown 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N2840 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Silvermont rev: 8 L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 8663 
           Speed: 536 MHz min/max: 500/2582 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 630 2: 710 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (BYT) v: 4.2 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-111-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: AzureWave AW-NE186H driver: ath9k v: kernel 
           port: f000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 
           bus ID: 03:00.2 
           IF: enp3s0f2 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 466.39 GiB (100.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST500LT012-1DG142 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 233.19 GiB (51.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 2.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 6280.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 2100 
Info:      Processes: 179 Uptime: 21m Memory: 3.74 GiB used: 1.03 GiB (27.5%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.5.0 
           clang: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.27
```

I've checked `top` and I don't see anything out of the ordinary that would cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with my computer's battery. I had a very weak battery that couldn't hold a charge. Once I got the battery replaced everything worked fine.